# Mosquitto broker: TCP retransmission

Tags: tcp, mosquitto, paho

I am using mosquitto as MQTT broker. I am using Paho Java library to connect to the broker with auto-reconnect as true. Normally, it works fine. Connection drop rate is there but auto-reconnect takes care of it. But sometimes, it looks like paho library is not attempting to auto connect. I captured network traffic in Wireshark:

[image]

Turns out that there are TCP retransmissions happening. As you can see, its happening continuously, and paho client is not able to reconnect. I am running client as well as server on same laptop, so I don't understand why failure / retransmission is happening.

Have anyone faced similar problem before?

OS: Windows 10.
Mosquitto and client, both are local processes

Comment: Tell us more about the environment? What OS? Are you using containers? It’s not the retransmissions that matter, it’s the changing port numbers and the resets. The trace shows two connection attempts by Paho which are getting TCP resets, which would indicate that nothing is listening on the MQTT port. It ‘s not that Paho isn’t trying to reconnect, it’s that the broker isn’t listening.

Comment: @romkey, My laptop is running Windows 10. Mosquitto and client, both are local processes, not containers